Date order issue in Scatter chart in PowerBI
I have a Power BI report that contains 2 tables. I am trying to plot a scatter chart from those 2 tables. One scatter chart shows dates in ascending order, but the other one is not showing the correct order. See screenshot below. How can I resolve this date order issue for the other table chart?


What is the data type of the Date column in your first table?

Both tables having date column of type date.

If you have no sorted dates in your records. You can create a calendar table using Date.List from M code. Relate the calendar to the above one from data model and it should work out.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

To fix the other chart, simply sort it by following these steps:

Click the 3 dots
Sort by date
Sort ascending

Then you should be good to go!

